# @Embedded on a subclass to include superclass's ID

Tags: java, hibernate

These are my classes:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Test_A 
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Integer aId;
    public  String bleh;
}

@Embeddable
public class Test_B extends Test_A 
{
    public String foo;
}

@Entity
public class Test_Main 
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Integer mainId;

    public Test_B testB;

    public Test_Main ()
    {
        testB = new Test_B();
        testB.foo="bar";
        testB.bleh="duh";
    }
}
```

This produces the following tables:

```
Table: Test_A
aId
bleh

Table: Test_Main
mainId
foo
```

Creating a new Test_Main and persisting it will populate the tables as follows:

```
Test_A: <blank>
Test_Main.mainId: 1
Test_Main.foo:    "bar"
```

Since Test_A's inheritance is JOINED, I was expecting to see a row in Test_A, with a foreign key in Test_main, as so:

```
Test_A.aId:  1
Test_A.bleh: "duh"

Test_Main.mainId: 1
Test_Main.aID:    1
Test_Main.foo:    "bar"
```

There are other subclasses of Test_A that must have their own tables, so JOINED is a requirement.  Is there any way for me to populate Test_A, and get a foreign key into Test_Main without needing a physical table for Test_B?

Comment: Having a class being both an entity and an embedded makes no sense. Either it has an identity (entity), or it's embedded inside another entity which has its own identity (embedded), but not both.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok, so is there any other way to get an FK in Test_Main to a row in Test_A that represents an instance of Test_B?

Comment: Other than changing the inheritance type to SINGLE_TABLE, no.